# Recursion extracting digits

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a a recursive function `getdigits(n)` that returns the list of digits in the positive integer n.

Example `getdigits(124) => [1,2,4]`

So far what I've got is:

```
def getdigits(n):
    if n<10:
        return [n]
    else:
        return [getdigits(n/10)]+[n%10]
```

But for 124 instead of `[1, 2, 4]` I get `[[[1], 2], 4]`

Working that in in my head it goes like:

```
getdigits(124) = [getdigits(12)] + [4]
getdigits(12) = [getdigits(1)] + [2]
get digits(1) = [1]
```

Therefore `getdigits(124) = [1] + [2] + [4] = [1, 2, 4]`

I figure there's something wrong in the second part of it as I can't see anything wrong with the condition, any suggestions without giving the entire solution away?

Comment: Does it have to be recursion? The simple solution would simply be `return list(str(n))`

Comment: So, then, why don't you return just 'getdigits(n/10) + [n%10]' instead of '[getdigits(n/10)] + [n%10]'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rewrite this function as a recursive function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568848/how-to-rewrite-this-function-as-a-recursive-function)

Comment: Added the homework tab - the only reason you would *need* a function to be recursive is homework. It's fine to post it on here, but tag it as such.

Comment: None of the functions posted so far is able to convert a 1000-digit long number. Can anyone write `getdigits` so that 1) it's recursive, 2) it doesn't exhaust the stack?

Comment: @thg435: those requirements are incompatible in python.  If you are using recursion, then you are consuming stack space.  It will run out.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: still, I think it's possible. You're going to need a decorator though.

Comment: @thg435: you think it's possible to write a recursive function in Python without consuming stack space?  I don't see how, and I don't see what a decorator would do for you.

Comment: @Ned: we can make it tail-recursive, and then apply a decorator that converts tail recursion to iteration.

Comment: @thg435: I don't think a decorator will be able to do that, they typically don't deal with the internals of the functions they wrap.  But if you manage it, lots of people would like to see it!

Comment: @Ned: someone already did that: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496691-new-tail-recursion-decorator

Comment: @thg435: ok, it's possible, but, ick.

Comment: @Ned: yes, this is a rather ugly hack, and unfortunately, [TRO/TCO is not going to be added to Python](http://neopythonic.blogspot.de/2009/04/final-words-on-tail-calls.html).

Answer (score 2):

getDigits return a list, so why do you wrap the list into another one (last line)?

Comment: Ahhh I didn't realise that until now, can't believe how slow I am.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is either that you're returning `[n]` instead of `n` or using `[getDigits(n / 10)]` instead of `getDigits(n / 10)`.

For instance, with your example:

```
getDigits(124) = [getDigits(12)] + [4] = [getDigits(12), 4]
getDigits(12) = [getDigits(1)] + [2] = [getDigits(1), 2]
getDigits(1) = [1]
```

Therefore it follows:

```
getDigits(12) = [[1], 2]
getDigits(124) = [[[1], 2], 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

The same question has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10568880/201359), see the link for more details.

```
def getdigits(n):
    if n < 10:
        return [n]
    return getdigits(n // 10) + [n % 10]

getdigits(123)
> [1, 2, 3]
```

The above will work for an integer n >= 0, notice that you don't have to wrap the result of `getdigits(n // 10)` inside *another* list.

Comment: Does python optimise recursive functions like this to avoid overloading the stack?

Comment: @Will no, Python doesn't [optimize tail recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13592002/201359).

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like homework (recursive requirement), but this could be done with a [`list comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> def getdigits(n):
...    return [int(y) for y in str(n)]
... 
>>> getdigits(12345)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

```
>>> num=124
>>>list(map(int,str(num)))
[1,2,4]
```

Comment: With which version of Python does this work? I can't get this to work on 2.7.3.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus edited my solution, made a silly mistake. :)\

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda

```
(lambda x: [int(a) for a in str(y)])(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getdigits(n):
    if n<10:
        return [n]
    else:
        return getdigits(n//10)+[n%10]
```

your answer is in float. You need to use floor division to make it [1] instead of 1.2