# Does Python optimize tail recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

I have the following piece of code which fails with the following error:

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

I attempted to rewrite this to allow for tail recursion optimization (TCO). I believe that this code should have been successful if a TCO had taken place.

```
def trisum(n, csum):
    if n == 0:
        return csum
    else:
        return trisum(n - 1, csum + n)

print(trisum(1000, 0))
```

Should I conclude that Python does not do any type of TCO, or do I just need to define it differently?

Comment: Python has no TCO implemented, It's believed to be too complex to implement in a dynamic language such as Python.

Comment: What is the code for initial recursion, which failed?

Comment: @Wessie TCO is simple regard of how dynamic or static the language is. Lua, for example, also does it. You merely need to recognize tail calls (pretty simple, both at AST level and at bytecode level), and then re-use the current stack frame instead of creating a new one (also simple, actually even simpler in interpreters than in native code).

Comment: Oh, one nitpick: You talk exclusively about tail recursion, but use the acronym "TCO", which means tail *call* optimization and applies to *any* instance of `return func(...)` (explicitly or implicitly), whether it's recursive or not. TCO is a proper superset of TRE, and more useful (e.g. it makes continuation passing style feasible, which TRE can't), and not much harder to implement.

Comment: Here is a hackish way to implement it - a decorator using exception raising to throw execution frames away: http://metapython.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/tail-recursion-elimination-in-python.html

Comment: Lisp has it, but I think wanting good trace backs is the trade off, you can not have both.

Comment: If you restrict yourself to tail recursion, I don't think a proper traceback is super-useful. You have a call to `foo` from inside a call to `foo` from inside to `foo` from inside a call to `foo`... I don't think any useful information would be lost from losing this.

Comment: I have recently learned about [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/) but have not tried it yet.  It looks worth taking a look at.  It is claimed to have tail recursion optimisation.

Comment: Please do not conflate Python (a programming language) with CPython (its most popular implementation). There is also [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) (and a few other, less important ones).

Answer (score 305, accepted):

No, and it never will since [Guido van Rossum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum) prefers to be able to have proper tracebacks:

*[Tail Recursion Elimination](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html)* (2009-04-22)

*[Final Words on Tail Calls](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/final-words-on-tail-calls.html)* (2009-04-27)

You can manually eliminate the recursion with a transformation like this:

```
>>> def trisum(n, csum):
...     while True:                     # Change recursion to a while loop
...         if n == 0:
...             return csum
...         n, csum = n - 1, csum + n   # Update parameters instead of tail recursion

>>> trisum(1000,0)
500500
```

Comment: Or if you're going to transform it like that - just: `from operator import add; reduce(add, xrange(n + 1), csum)` ?

Comment: @JonClements, that works in this particular example. The transformation to a while loop works for tail recursion in general cases.

Comment: +1 For being the correct answer but this seems like an incredibly bone-headed design decision. The [reasons given](http://neopythonic.blogspot.fr/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html) seem to boil down to "it's hard to do given how python is interpreted and I don't like it anyway so there!"

Comment: @Basic No, but you have to read the article you're commenting on. It seems very strongly that you didn't actually read it, considering how it "boils down" to you. (You might actually need to read both of the linked articles, unfortunately, since some arguments are spread over both.) It has almost nothing to do with implementation of the language, but everything to do with the intended semantics.

Comment: @Veky I have read the article I was commenting on. Just because GVR decides to highlight the flaws with the approaches some people have taken to work around this gap in the language, I don't see how that becomes an argument against a feature.  You say "It has almost nothing to do with implementation of the language, but everything to do with the intended semantics." which brings me back to my first point. Tail recursion can be an elegant way to solve a problem. Refusing to support it because the syntax wouldn't be "pythonic" seems pretty bone-headed.

Comment: Ok, I give up. Now you're talking about _syntax_, which is even less relevant to original Guido's point than the implementation. On the other hand, you never even _mention_ debugging, which is Guido's main argument. It's obvious we look at the same thing and see it very differently. A matter of perspective, I guess. :-)

Comment: interesting... I'm curious but how does this eventually break out of the `while` loop? There's no break explicitly define or nothing that would appear to make `while True` be `False`...

Comment: @Mangohero1, the loop is broken by the `return`. Note that -ve values of `n` will loop forever.

Comment: Some important arguments in favor of tail recursion, outside of TCO being supported or not, are being overlooked. First, some algorithms are so difficult to express non-recursively that it's not practical to write them that way (e.g. Karatsuba multiplication).  Secondly, tail recursion should still be preferred over other types of recursion even if TCO isn't supported by the language because it minimizes the size of each recursive call on the stack (so I have to disagree with Baruchel's answer, below, on that one point - you should care where the recursive call happens even without TCO).

Comment: Why do you do `while True: if n == 0: return csum; ...`  instead of `while n != 0: ...; return csum`? Just curious.

Comment: “Third, I don't believe in recursion as the basis of all programming”. This looks like the real reason

Comment: Note that such a `while True:` loop will only work for functions which call themselves directly. It won't work for mutually-recursive calls, e.g. like `isOdd(3) -> isEven(2) -> isOdd(1) -> isEven(0) -> True`. It also won't work for higher-order code, like continuation-passing (where the function we're calling is taken as an argument)

Answer (score 223):

I published a module performing tail-call optimization (handling both tail-recursion and continuation-passing style): https://github.com/baruchel/tco

## Optimizing tail-recursion in Python

It has often been claimed that tail-recursion doesn't suit the Pythonic way of coding and that one shouldn't care about how to embed it in a loop. I don't want to argue with
this point of view; sometimes however I like trying or implementing new ideas
as tail-recursive functions rather than with loops for various reasons (focusing on the
idea rather than on the process, having twenty short functions on my screen in the same
time rather than only three "Pythonic" functions, working in an interactive session rather than editing my code, etc.).

Optimizing tail-recursion in Python is in fact quite easy. While it is said to be impossible
or very tricky, I think it can be achieved with elegant, short and general solutions; I even
think that most of these solutions don't use Python features otherwise than they should.
Clean lambda expressions working along with very standard loops lead to quick, efficient and
fully usable tools for implementing tail-recursion optimization.

As a personal convenience, I wrote a small module implementing such an optimization
by two different ways. I would like to discuss here about my two main functions.

### The clean way: modifying the Y combinator

The [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator) is well known; it allows to use lambda functions in a recursive
manner, but it doesn't allow by itself to embed recursive calls in a loop. Lambda
calculus alone can't do such a thing. A slight change in the Y combinator however
can protect the recursive call to be actually evaluated. Evaluation can thus be delayed.

Here is the famous expression for the Y combinator:

```
lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda *args: y(y)(*args)))
```

With a very slight change, I could get:

```
lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda *args: lambda: y(y)(*args)))
```

Instead of calling itself, the function f now returns a function performing the
very same call, but since it returns it, the evaluation can be done later from outside.

My code is:

```
def bet(func):
    b = (lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y:
          f(lambda *args: lambda: y(y)(*args))))(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        out = b(*args)
        while callable(out):
            out = out()
        return out
    return wrapper
```

The function can be used in the following way; here are two examples with tail-recursive
versions of factorial and Fibonacci:

```
>>> from recursion import *
>>> fac = bet( lambda f: lambda n, a: a if not n else f(n-1,a*n) )
>>> fac(5,1)
120
>>> fibo = bet( lambda f: lambda n,p,q: p if not n else f(n-1,q,p+q) )
>>> fibo(10,0,1)
55
```

Obviously recursion depth isn't an issue any longer:

```
>>> bet( lambda f: lambda n: 42 if not n else f(n-1) )(50000)
42
```

This is of course the single real purpose of the function.

Only one thing can't be done with this optimization: it can't be used with a
tail-recursive function evaluating to another function (this comes from the fact
that callable returned objects are all handled as further recursive calls with
no distinction). Since I usually don't need such a feature, I am very happy
with the code above. However, in order to provide a more general module, I thought
a little more in order to find some workaround for this issue (see next section).

Concerning the speed of this process (which isn't the real issue however), it happens
to be quite good; tail-recursive functions are even evaluated much quicker than with
the following code using simpler expressions:

```
def bet1(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        out = func(lambda *x: lambda: x)(*args)
        while callable(out):
            out = func(lambda *x: lambda: x)(*out())
        return out
    return wrapper
```

I think that evaluating one expression, even complicated, is much quicker than
evaluating several simple expressions, which is the case in this second version.
I didn't keep this new function in my module, and I see no circumstances where it
could be used rather than the "official" one.

### Continuation passing style with exceptions

Here is a more general function; it is able to handle all tail-recursive functions,
including those returning other functions. Recursive calls are recognized from
other return values by the use of exceptions. This solutions is slower than the
previous one; a quicker code could probably be written by using some special
values as "flags" being detected in the main loop, but I don't like the idea of
using special values or internal keywords. There is some funny interpretation
of using exceptions: if Python doesn't like tail-recursive calls, an exception
should be raised when a tail-recursive call does occur, and the Pythonic way will be
to catch the exception in order to find some clean solution, which is actually what
happens here...

```
class _RecursiveCall(Exception):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.args = args
def _recursiveCallback(*args):
  raise _RecursiveCall(*args)
def bet0(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        while True:
          try:
            return func(_recursiveCallback)(*args)
          except _RecursiveCall as e:
            args = e.args
    return wrapper
```

Now all functions can be used. In the following example, `f(n)` is evaluated to the
identity function for any positive value of n:

```
>>> f = bet0( lambda f: lambda n: (lambda x: x) if not n else f(n-1) )
>>> f(5)(42)
42
```

Of course, it could be argued that exceptions are not intended to be used for intentionally
redirecting the interpreter (as a kind of `goto` statement or probably rather a kind of
continuation passing style), which I have to admit. But, again,
I find funny the idea of using `try` with a single line being a `return` statement: we try to return
something (normal behaviour) but we can't do it because of a recursive call occurring (exception).

**Initial answer (2013-08-29).**

I wrote a very small plugin for handling tail recursion. You may find it with my explanations there: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr#!topic/comp.lang.python/dIsnJ2BoBKs

It can embed a lambda function written with a tail recursion style in another function which will evaluate it as a loop.

The most interesting feature in this small function, in my humble opinion, is that the function doesn't rely on some dirty programming hack but on mere lambda calculus: the behaviour of the function is changed to another one when inserted in another lambda function which looks very like the Y combinator.

Comment: Could you, please, provide an example of defining a function (preferably in way similar to a normal definition) which tail-calls one of several other functions based on some condition, using your method? Also, can your wrapping function `bet0` be used as a decorator for class methods?

Comment: @Alexey I am not sure I can write code in a block-style inside a comment, but you can of course use the `def` syntax for your functions, and actually the last example above relies on a condition. In my post http://baruchel.github.io/python/2015/11/07/explaining-functional-aspects-in-python/ you can see a paragraph beginning with "Of course you could object that nobody would write such a code" where I give an example with the usual definition syntax. For the second part of your question, I have to think about it a little more since I haven't spent time in that for a while. Regards.

Comment: You should care where the recursive call happens in your function even if you are using a non-TCO language implementation.  This is because the portion of the function that occurs after the recursive call is the portion that needs to get stored on the stack.  Therefore, making your function tail-recursive minimizes the amount of information you have to store per recursive call, which gives you more room to have large recursive call stacks if you need them.

Answer (score 24):

The word of Guido is at http://neopythonic.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html

> I recently posted an entry in my Python History blog on the origins of
>   Python's functional features. A side remark about not supporting tail
>   recursion elimination (TRE) immediately sparked several comments about
>   what a pity it is that Python doesn't do this, including links to
>   recent blog entries by others trying to "prove" that TRE can be added
>   to Python easily. So let me defend my position (which is that I don't
>   want TRE in the language). If you want a short answer, it's simply
>   unpythonic. Here's the long answer:

Comment: And herein lies the problem with so-called BDsFL.

Comment: @AdamDonahue have you been perfectly satisfied with every decision that's come from a committee? At least you get a reasoned and authoritative explanation from the BDFL.

Comment: No, of course not, but they strike me as more even-handed.  This from a prescriptivist, not a descriptivist. The irony.

Answer (score 9):

[CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) does not and will probably never support tail call optimization based on [Guido van Rossum's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum) statements on the subject.

I've heard arguments that it makes debugging more difficult because of how it modifies the stack trace.

Comment: @mux CPython is the reference implementation of the programming language Python. There are other implementations (such as PyPy, IronPython, and Jython), which implement the same language but differ in implementation details. The distinction is useful here because (in theory) it's possible to create an alternative Python implementation that does TCO. I'm not aware of anyone even thinking about it though, and usefulness would be limited as code relying on it would break on all other Python implementations.

Answer (score 4):

Try the experimental [macropy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tail-call-optimization) TCO implementation for size.

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in tail recursion optimization in Python. However, we can "rebuild" the function through the Abstract Syntax Tree( AST), eliminating the recursion there and replacing it with a loop. Guido was absolutely right, this approach has some limitations, so I can't recommend it for use.

However, I still wrote (rather as a training example) my own version of the optimizer, and you can even try how it works.

Install this package via pip:

```
pip install astrologic
```

Now you can run this sample code:

```
from astrologic import no_recursion

counter = 0

@no_recursion
def recursion():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    if counter != 10000000:
        return recursion()
    return counter

print(recursion())
```

This solution is not stable, and you should never use it in production. You can read about some significant restrictions on the [page in github](https://github.com/pomponchik/astrologic) (in Russian, sorry). However, this solution is quite "real", without interrupting the code and other similar tricks.

Answer (score 4):

A tail call can never be *optimized* to a jump in Python. An optimization is a program transformation that preserves the program's meaning. Tail-call elimination doesn't preserve the meaning of Python programs.

One problem, often mentioned, is that tail-call elimination changes the call stack, and Python allows for runtime introspection of the stack. But there is another problem that is rarely mentioned. There is probably a lot of code like this in the wild:

```
def map_file(path):
    f = open(path, 'rb')
    return mmap.mmap(f.fileno())
```

The call to `mmap.mmap` is in tail position. If it were replaced by a jump, then the current stack frame would be discarded before control was passed to `mmap`. The current stack frame contains the only reference to the file object, so the file object could (and in CPython would) be freed before `mmap` is called, which would close the file descriptor, invalidating it before `mmap` sees it.

At best, the code would fail with an exception. At worst, the file descriptor could be reused in another thread, causing `mmap` to map the wrong file. So this "optimization" would be a potentially disastrous thing to unleash on the huge body of existing Python code.

The Python spec guarantees that such problems won't occur, so you can be sure that no conformant implementation will ever convert `return f(args)` into a jump—unless, perhaps, it has a sophisticated static analysis engine that can prove that discarding an object early will have no observable consequences in this case.

---

None of that would prevent Python from adding a syntax for *explicit* tail calls with jump semantics, such as

```
    return from f(args)
```

That wouldn't break code that didn't use it, and it would probably be useful for autogenerated code and some algorithms. GvR is no longer BDFL, so it might happen, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 2):

Besides optimizing tail recursion, you can set the recursion depth manually by:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5500000)
print("recursion limit:%d " % (sys.getrecursionlimit()))
```

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery?

Comment: Because it _also_ doesn't offer TCO? :-D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660577/are-any-javascript-engines-tail-call-optimized