# How can I define algebraic data types in Python?

Tags: python, algebraic-data-types

How can I define algebraic data types in Python (2 or 3)?

Comment: Python has a very loose type system in the first place; what exactly are you trying to get out of this?

Comment: @Amber not loose. very strong, but duck.

Comment: @Elazar When I say "loose", I mean things like functions not having particular type signatures. But you're right, Python is not weakly typed.

Comment: @Amber I see what you mean.

Comment: @Amber Rather than "loose" maybe saying it's dynamically typed rather than statically typed would have been clearer.

Comment: @Elazar But there also some amount implicit type conversions.

Comment: Type conversions such as?

Answer (score 58):

### Python 3.10 version

Here is a Python 3.10 version of [Brent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258553/how-can-i-define-algebraic-data-types-in-python#answer-64578832) with pattern-matching and prettier union type syntax:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float

@dataclass
class Circle:
    x: float
    y: float
    r: float

@dataclass
class Rectangle:
    x: float
    y: float
    w: float
    h: float

Shape = Point | Circle | Rectangle

def print_shape(shape: Shape):
    match shape:
        case Point(x, y):
            print(f"Point {x} {y}")
        case Circle(x, y, r):
            print(f"Circle {x} {y} {r}")
        case Rectangle(x, y, w, h):
            print(f"Rectangle {x} {y} {w} {h}")

print_shape(Point(1, 2))
print_shape(Circle(3, 5, 7))
print_shape(Rectangle(11, 13, 17, 19))
print_shape(4)  # mypy type error
```

You can even do recursive types:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Branch:
    value: int
    left: Tree
    right: Tree

Tree = Branch | None

def contains(tree: Tree, value: int):
    match tree:
        case None:
            return False
        case Branch(x, left, right):
            return x == value or contains(left, value) or contains(right, value)

tree = Branch(1, Branch(2, None, None), Branch(3, None, Branch(4, None, None)))

assert contains(tree, 1)
assert contains(tree, 2)
assert contains(tree, 3)
assert contains(tree, 4)
assert not contains(tree, 5)
```

Note the need for `from __future__ import annotations` in order to annotate with a type that hasn't been defined yet.

Exhaustiveness checking for ADTs can be enforced with [`mypy`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) using [`typing.assert_never()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.assert_never) in Python 3.11+ or as part of the [`typing-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) backport for older versions of Python.

```py
def print_shape(shape: Shape):
    match shape:
        case Point(x, y):
            print(f"Point {x} {y}")
        case Circle(x, y, r):
            print(f"Circle {x} {y} {r}")
        case _ as unreachable:
            # mypy will throw a type checking error
            # because Rectangle is not covered in the match.
            assert_never(unreachable)
```

Comment: Great answer! Not that [python does not optimize tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion) and the `contains` function will use one stack frame per tree level. Given the logarithmic height of binary trees, this should be fine, just something to be aware of

Comment: @SimonKohlmeyer No language, even ones with tail call optimization/elimination, should be able to eliminate the tail in this case, as far as I can see. The `contains` branches *twice*, so only `contains(right, value)` is in tail position, while the prior one, `contains(left, value)` is not. The `or` operation follows it in any case and no tail can be eliminated (the locals are still required after returning from it). So this always uses a stack frame per level, regardless if Python supported TCO.

Comment: There's a [project on Github](https://github.com/0scarB/tail-recursive) to implement tail recursion for Python. I haven't tried using it, and can't vouch for it, but I'm aware it exists.

Comment: As I pointed out in Brent's answer, sum and union types are different.

Answer (score 27):

The `typing` module provides `Union` which, dissimilar to C, is a sum type. You'll need to use mypy to do static type checking, and there's a notable lack of pattern matching, but combined with tuples (product types), that's the two common algebraic types.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union


@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float


@dataclass
class Circle:
    x: float
    y: float
    r: float


@dataclass
class Rectangle:
    x: float
    y: float
    w: float
    h: float


Shape = Union[Point, Circle, Rectangle]


def print_shape(shape: Shape):
    if isinstance(shape, Point):
        print(f"Point {shape.x} {shape.y}")
    elif isinstance(shape, Circle):
        print(f"Circle {shape.x} {shape.y} {shape.r}")
    elif isinstance(shape, Rectangle):
        print(f"Rectangle {shape.x} {shape.y} {shape.w} {shape.h}")


print_shape(Point(1, 2))
print_shape(Circle(3, 5, 7))
print_shape(Rectangle(11, 13, 17, 19))
# print_shape(4)  # mypy type error
```

Comment: Hi! If you are using mypy, you can check the exhaustiveness of your "pattern matching" using the `assert_never` idiom: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/735

Comment: And PEP 622 (pattern matching) makes using sum types even more similar to functional languages.

Comment: This isn't really sum types since it just relies on RTTI to identify the type.

Comment: As of today (October 15 2021) Python 3.10 is released, adding support for structural pattern matching. https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#summary-release-highlights

Comment: Sum and union types are two different things. `None | None`, for example, is isomorphic (if not identical) to `None` itself. `None + None` (to use the obvious syntax for a hypothetical sum type) would be isomorphic to `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

there is a library that does exactly what you want called [ADT](https://pypi.org/project/algebraic-data-types), it even has mypy typechecking. However it is unmaintained so use it with caution ig.

the code using it looks like this

```py
@adt
class Tree:
    EMPTY: Case
    LEAF: Case[int]
    NODE: Case["Tree", "Tree"]
```

and matching works too

```py
# Defined in some other module, perhaps
def some_operation() -> Either[Exception, int]:
    return Either.RIGHT(22)  # Example of building a constructor

# Run some_operation, and handle the success or failure
default_value = 5
unpacked_result = some_operation().match(
    # In this case, we're going to ignore any exception we receive
    left=lambda ex: default_value,
    right=lambda result: result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of structural pattern matching in Python 3.10, ADTs in Python became practical

```html
from typing import Union
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Circle:
    radius: float

@dataclass
class Rectangle:
    width: float
    height: float

@dataclass
class Triangle:
    base: float
    height: float

Shape = Circle | Rectangle | Triangle

def area(shape: Shape) -> float:
    match shape:
        case Circle(radius):
            return 3.14159 * radius ** 2
        case Rectangle(width, height):
            return width * height
        case Triangle(base, height):
            return 0.5 * base * height

# Example usage
circle = Circle(radius=5)
print("Area of circle:", area(circle))

rectangle = Rectangle(height=10, width=5)
print("Area of rectangle:", area(rectangle))

triangle = Triangle(base=10, height=5)
print("Area of triangle:", area(triangle))
```

I would argue @dataclass is how Python supports Product types. And in line 18th, you'll see Python already supports Union Types. That enables us to create a Shape relationship (Type) without resorting to inheritance.

The big problem before 3.10 was the lack of Pattern Matching, which meant discriminating between the concrete shape required chained if-elif-else/instanceOf chains.

With pattern matching, we can express the cases directly and cleanly. To my surprise, `mypy` will give you an error if the pattern matching is not exhaustive.

I am disappointed that Python implemented match as a statement, not an expression, but I am guessing that an expression might have looked weird to long-time Pythonistas.

The above shows Python's support for ADTs is adequate, given the limitations of a dynamically typed imperative language.

If interested in a longer explanation, you could look at my [blog](https://www.turingtaco.com/pythons-path-to-embracing-algebraic-data-types/)

Answer (score -3):

Here's an implementation of sum types in relatively Pythonic way.

```
import attr


@attr.s(frozen=True)
class CombineMode(object):
    kind = attr.ib(type=str)
    params = attr.ib(factory=list)

    def match(self, expected_kind, f):
        if self.kind == expected_kind:
            return f(*self.params)
        else:
            return None

    @classmethod
    def join(cls):
        return cls("join")

    @classmethod
    def select(cls, column: str):
        return cls("select", params=[column])
```

Crack open an interpreter and you'll see familiar behavior:

```
>>> CombineMode.join()
CombineMode(kind='join_by_entity', params=[])

>>> CombineMode.select('a') == CombineMode.select('b')
False

>>> CombineMode.select('a') == CombineMode.select('a')
True

>>> CombineMode.select('foo').match('select', print)
foo
```

Note: The `@attr.s` decorator comes from the [attrs library](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html), it implements `__init__`, `__repr__`, and `__eq__`, but it also freezes the object. I included it because it cuts down on the implementation size, but it's also widely available and quite stable.

Sum types are sometimes called tagged unions. Here I used the `kind` member to implement the tag. Additional per-variant parameters are implemented via a list. In true Pythonic fashion, this is duck-typed on the input & output sides but not strictly enforced internally.

I also included a `match` function that does basic pattern matching. Type safety is also implemented via duck typing, a `TypeError` will be raised if the passed lambda's function signature doesn't align with the actual variant you're trying to match on.

These sum types can be combined with product types (`list` or `tuple`) and still retain a lot of the critical functionality required for algebraic data types.

**Problems**

This doesn't strictly constrain the set of variants.