# How to create Haskell-like sum types in Python?

Tags: python-typing, sum-type

If I have some simple sum type in Haskell, like

```hs
data Owner = Me | You
```

How do I express that in Python in a convenient way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify multiple return types using type-hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints)

Comment: @Georgy Unfortunately no. That answer shows how to express `classes` of values, i.e., `int` or `str`. I want to limit it to `values`, i.e., `1` and `2`, or the strings `me` and `you`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you are looking for [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Literal). Here is a fitting duplicate question: [Type hint for a function that returns only a specific set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39398138/7851470)

Comment: Are you looking for static types or runtime types? An enum might be appropriate for the latter.

Comment: For the other commenters the poster is asking about a tagged union or sum types https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I define algebraic data types in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258553/how-can-i-define-algebraic-data-types-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enum or a Union is the closest thing to a `tagged union` or `sum type` in Python

#### Enum

```py
from enum import Enum

class Owner(Enum):
     Me = 1
     You = 2
```

#### Union

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

```py
import typing

class Me:
    pass
class You:
    pass

owner: typing.Union[Me, You] = Me
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could try to translate the sample given in the question. While these constructs are theoretically close, it's not entirely clear to me that these two actually match the desired *effect*. Since Python values are natively "tagged" with their type, the effect of a tagged union may be achieved otherwise – for example, by doing nothing.