# How can I create a union type that can also be used to instantiate union members in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing, algebraic-data-types, discriminated-union

I'm currently building an algebraic data type to represent the state of a task, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258553/how-can-i-define-algebraic-data-types-in-python), but want to extend it to make it a little cleaner to use.

Here are the definitions of my states:

```py
@dataclass
class StatusWaiting:
    # Nothing
    pass

@dataclass
class StatusRunning:
    progress: float

@dataclass
class StatusComplete:
    result: int

@dataclass
class StatusFailure:
    reason: str
```

However, the way that I intend to use these variants has two seemingly incompatible behaviours:

Type annotation should behave as follows:

```py
Status = StatusWaiting | StatusRunning | StatusComplete | StatusFailure

def get_status() -> Status:
    ...
```

Instantiation should behave as follows:

```py
class Status:
    Waiting = StatusWaiting
    Running = StatusRunning
    Failed = StatusFailed
    Complete = StatusComplete

my_status = Status.Running(0.42)
```

How can I define the `Status` type so that I can have it behave as a union when used as a type annotation, and also behave as a collection of the variants for simple initialization?

```py
Status = ???

def get_status() -> Status:
    return Status.Failed("Something has gone horribly wrong")
```

I've tried using an `Enum`, but this doesn't appear to allow for instantiation.

```py
class Status(Enum):
    Waiting = StatusWaiting
    Running = StatusRunning
    Complete = StatusComplete
    Failure = StatusFailure


def get_status() -> Status:
    # Mypy: "Status" not callable
    return Status.Complete(42)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a `Status` abstract base class containing `classmethod` functions to create each variant of the system.

Since all of the variants inherit the `Status` class, they can all be annotated as `Status` for type-checking.

The downside of this approach is that all the Status variants do have those `classmethod`s available.

```py
# We need the __annotations__ feature since our definitions contain
# circular references
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass


# Abstract base class with class methods to instantiate each variant
class Status(ABC):
    @classmethod
    def Waiting(cls) -> StatusWaiting:
        return StatusWaiting()

    @classmethod
    def Running(cls, progress: float) -> StatusRunning:
        return StatusRunning(progress)

    @classmethod
    def Complete(cls, result: int) -> StatusComplete:
        return StatusComplete(result)

    @classmethod
    def Failure(cls, reason: str) -> StatusFailure:
        return StatusFailure(reason)


@dataclass
class StatusWaiting(Status):
    # Nothing
    pass


@dataclass
class StatusRunning(Status):
    progress: float


@dataclass
class StatusComplete(Status):
    result: int


@dataclass
class StatusFailure(Status):
    reason: str


# This is type-safe
def get_status() -> Status:
    return Status.Failure("Something has gone horribly wrong")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked like a charm! The downside you mentioned is manageable, although a little unpleasant. The slightly more annoying aspect is the requirement for duplicate code and documentation, but I think sacrificing library cleanliness for usability is a worthwhile trade-off.