# Non brute force solution to Project Euler problem 25

Tags: python, fibonacci

[Project Euler problem 25](https://projecteuler.net/problem=25):

> The Fibonacci sequence is defined by the recurrence relation:
>
> F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n−1</sub> + F<sub>n−2</sub>, where F<sub>1 = 1</sub> and F<sub>2</sub> = 1. Hence the first 12 terms
> will be F<sub>1</sub> = 1, F<sub>2</sub> = 1, F<sub>3</sub> = 2, F<sub>4</sub> = 3, F<sub>5</sub> = 5, F<sub>6</sub> = 8, F<sub>7</sub> = 13, F<sub>8</sub> =
> 21, F<sub>9</sub> = 34, F<sub>10</sub> = 55, F<sub>11</sub> = 89, F<sub>12</sub> = 144
>
> The 12th term, F<sub>12</sub>, is the first term to contain three digits.
>
> What is the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000
> digits?

I made a brute force solution in Python but it takes forever. Can anyone suggest a non brute force solution?

```
def Fibonacci(NthTerm):
    if NthTerm == 1 or NthTerm == 2:
        return 1 # Challenge defines 1st and 2nd term as == 1
    else:  # recursive definition of Fib term
        return Fibonacci(NthTerm-1) + Fibonacci(NthTerm-2)

FirstTerm = 0 # For scope to include Term in scope of print on line 13
for Term in range(1, 1000): # Arbitrary range
    FibValue = str(Fibonacci(Term)) # Convert integer to string for len()
    if len(FibValue) == 1000:
        FirstTerm = Term
        break # Stop there
    else:
        continue # Go to next number
print "The first term in the\nFibonacci sequence to\ncontain 1000 digits\nis the", FirstTerm, "term."
```

Comment: a brute-force solution does not need to take for ever. it is your recursion that is way too slow. just google for a better fibonacci algorithm

Comment: Your bruteforce complexity is horrible, you got O(2^n). Try to use three arguments: the number of terms to create, and the two previous results. That what you'll get linear time, and it should be fast enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write a fibonacci function that runs in linear time and with constant memory footprint, you don't need a list to keep them.
Here's a recursive version (however, if n is big enough, it will just [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion))

```
def fib(a, b, n):
    if n == 1:
        return a
    else: 
        return fib(a+b, a, n-1)


print fib(1, 0, 10) # prints 55
```

This function calls itself only once (resulting in around N calls for a parameter N), in contrast with your solution which calls itself twice (around 2^N calls for a parameter N).

Here's a version that won't ever stackoverflow and uses a loop instead of recursion:

```
def fib(n):
    a = 1
    b = 0
    while n > 1:
        a, b = a+b, a
        n = n - 1
    return a

print fib(100000)
```

And that's fast enough:

```
$ time python fibo.py 
3364476487643178326662161200510754331030214846068006390656476...

real    0m0.869s
```

But calling `fib` until you get a result big enough isn't perfect: the first numbers of the serie are calculated multiple times.
You can calculate the next fibonacci number and check its size in the same loop:

```
a = 1
b = 0
n = 1
while len(str(a)) != 1000:
    a, b = a+b, a
    n = n + 1
print "%d has 1000 digits, n = %d" % (a, n)
```

Comment: Your first function isn't *"linear time and with constant memory"*. Both time and memory are **quadratic**.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'd take the argument that it's O(log(N)) if we were to take into account python's auto-growing integers, or O(n) given python doesn't do tail call optimisation, but I'd love to see your work for claiming it's quadratic :)

Comment: The number values grow exponentially, which means their size grows linearly. And you compute linearly many.

Answer (score 2):

Why hasn't anybody used generators for this?  This is a brute force solution, but it is very quick:

```
def fibo():
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while True:
        yield b
        a,b = b,a+b
```

This gives a generator that computes the Fibonacci sequence.  For example

```
f = fibo()
[next(f) for i in range(10)]
```

produces

```
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
```

Using this, we can solve the problem like so:

```
f = enumerate(fibo())
x = 0
while len(str(x)) < 1000:
    i,x = next(f)

print("The %d-th term has %d digits"%(i+1,len(str(x))))
```

This produces the output

```
The 4782-th term has 1000 digits
```

The generator computes the sequence and produces terms 1 by 1 and this solution runs nearly instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Two things can be optimized a lot with one little change in your code. These two things are:

- You compute each fibonacci number using two other fibonacci numbers, resulting in an exponential complexity (which explodes even if you'd only compute a single but high fibonacci number).
- You don't remember any previous computed fibonacci number to compute the next in your loop.

Simply remember all computed fibonacci numbers as a private implementation detail in `Fibonacci` and you get rid of both performance problems. You can do this by using a simple dynamic array to which you add the result if it wasn't cached before.

Pseudo-code (I don't speak Python but this can be easily implemented):

```
def Fibonacci(NthTerm):
    if (cache contains NthTerm)
        return cache[NthTerm]
    else
        FibValue = Fibonacci(NthTerm-1) + Fibonacci(NthTerm-2)
        cache[NthTerm] = FibValue
        return FibValue
```

This will result in very restricted recurion, since you compute the N-th fibonacci number only if you already know (and cached) the (N-1)-th number.

This optimization works even if you need *any* fibonacci number (for future problems), but in this particular case we know that we only need to remember the last two numbers since we're never going to ask for old numbers again. So you don't need a whole list of numbers but only two, which you "cycle through" for each step in your main loop. Something like

```
f1, f2 = f2, f1 + f2
```

within the loop and an initialization like

```
f1, f2 = 1, 1
```

will essentially replace your function `Fibonacci` and its performance problems, but it restricts you to this limited use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Java version in constant space and linear time:

```
    static int q24(){
    int index = 3;
    BigInteger fn_2 = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger fn_1 = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger fn   = fn_1.add(fn_2);
    while(fn.toString().length()<1000){
        fn_2 = fn_1;
        fn_1 = fn;
        fn = fn_2.add(fn_1);
        index++;
    }       
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [newton's approximation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) on [binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html). The idea is to find a tangent line on the graph and use the x-intercept of that line to approximate the value of the zero of the graph.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Memorization :

```
m={}

def fub(n):
     if n not in m:
        if n <= 2 :
           m[n] =  1
        else:
           m[n] =  fub(n-1) + fub(n-2)

     return m[n]

i=1
while len(str(fub(i))) != 1000:
   i+=1
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, a very simple solution.

```
import java.math.BigInteger
val bound: BigInteger = BigInteger.TEN.pow(999)
var index = 2
var fib = BigInteger.ONE
var prevFib = BigInteger.ONE
while (fib < bound) {
    prevFib = fib.also { fib += prevFib }
    index++
}
println(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a further optimization: check the length not via string length but via comparison to the smallest int with the desired number of digits. Benchmark for 1000 and 4000 digits:

```
n=1000
fibo_int 4782  0.00062 seconds
fibo_str 4782  0.03403 seconds

n=4000
fibo_int 19137  0.01066 seconds
fibo_str 19137  1.86070 seconds
```

Code:

```py
from time import perf_counter as time

def fibo_int(n):
    a = b = i = 1
    goal = 10**(n-1)
    while a < goal:
        a, b, i = b, a+b, i+1
    return i

def fibo_str(n):
    a = b = i = 1
    while len(str(a)) < n:
        a, b, i = b, a+b, i+1
    return i

funcs = fibo_int, fibo_str

for n in 1000, 4000:
    print(f'{n=}')
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = time()
        print(f.__name__, f(n), f' {time() - t0:.5f} seconds')
    print()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVFRasMwDGW_OYX-ErdJSWGDUdazGCeVV0MiB9thjNKT7Kc_2zV2j51msp12-xrMINmW3tOzrLeP6TUcLV0u73PQzePX3ad2doRgRgQzTtYFmNBp2duZAjpQPuWK4oAatOmsNBQqErsCeCnYQ8dm2LYp8mzVEC_talVRsxUp-HI0AzL4KaUzNdFr6OpE5k2t43mdyzgMsyMwv3R9cH_oZokBqYo4JQSL0f-U9Ey9Z8S1y_qmyznrgEHEjbVtDffsc_HJxf_Q5Yn25zJ3G7E6YlPBnzeElovHz6zELbbQN1KSGlFK1uQm2ZdwylBomLjbPOgzeOwtHfwik6kiz3EZ53Ws3w)

Answer (score 0):

Just seeing this 10 years after the fact. But I feel the expected answer has not been given yet ("expected answer" since it is a challenge and comes from a maths oriented site. As a math teacher myself, I feel that this kind of question is precisely there to see who will use brute force and who will think otherwise)

So far, the fastest is Kelly Bundy's one.

0.00053 seconds (he said 0.00062, I guess my PC is faster)

But, at least for high number, estimate very precisely the number of digits of Fibonacci sequence, without computing them all.

We know that Fₙ=1/√5 (φⁿ-φ'ⁿ)
With φ=(1+√5)/2 and φ'=(1-√5)/2
Since φ' is less than 1, we can forget it, for a while

The number of digits of φⁿ/√5 is  floor(log(φⁿ/√5)/log(10))+1 (+1 because log₁₀(10)=1, log₁₀(100)=2, ... So there is one more digit each times)

So we are looking for n such as log(φⁿ/√5)/log(10)+1 ≥ 1000, so log(φⁿ/√5)/log(10) ≥ 999 ⇒ log(φⁿ/√5) ≥ 999·log(10) ⇒ n·log(φ)-½·log(5) ≥ 999·log(10) ⇒ n ≥ (999·log(10)+½·log(5))/log(φ)

Let's just compute that

```py
import math
phi=(1+math.sqrt(5))/2
phip=(1-math.sqrt(5))/2 # We'll need that later
n=math.ceil((999*math.log(10)+0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(phi))
```

Which gives 4782

We are not exactly there yet (tho it is the correct answer).
We need to check the φ' part, and potential numerical error.

But that's easily done. The part we neglected is
(φ'⁴⁷⁸²)/√5, whose decimal logarithm is `(4782*math.log(-phip)-0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(10)`
So it is 0.{998 zeros} and a digit.

Numerical error on such computation is around 1e-16. So, numerical error, not φ'ⁿ, is the only thing we should worry about.

But F₄₇₈₂ whose log₁₀ is

```
l10=(4782*math.log(phi)-0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(10)
```

That is it is, since `10**(l10-int(l10))` is 1.07..., it is 107 followed by 997 zeros.
So the numerical error (plus the φ'ⁿ) would had to be 7% of that simple computation so that we misestimate number of digits. So we can be 100% certain that F₄₇₈₂ has 1000 digits

Let's also check that F₄₇₈₁ has only 999

```
k10=(4781*math.log(phi)-0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(10)
print(int(k10)+1, 10**(k10-int(k10)))
# 999 6.61...
```

So F₄₇₈₁ is a number starting with a 6 and followed by 998 other digits. It would take a >30% error to confuse this with a number of 1000 digits. So, there again, we are 100% certain that F₄₇₈₁ is a 999 digits number.

Hence my version

```py
def fibo_binet(size):
    phi=(1+math.sqrt(5))/2
    n=math.ceil(((size-1)*math.log(10)+0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(phi))
    l10=(n*math.log(phi)-0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(10)
    k10=((n-1)*math.log(phi)-0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(10)
    if int(l10)==int(k10)+1 and (l10-int(l10))>1e-14 and (k10-int(k10))>1e-14:
       return n
    else:
       return f"unsure between {n-1} and {n}"
```

Timing this time is
0.00000134 (1.34 μs, compared to Kelly's int version 530 μs). And of course, this is O(1), so for n=4000, I takes (1.32 μs — the 0.02 μs less are obviously just noise — vs 4279 μs for Kelly's)

One may object that there is the risk of not being sure. But, at least I do take time to check that, so we are sure to be sure when we are :D.
(being sure is even the most time consuming part of my code)

And I've checked: for any number of digits between 2 and 20000000, the result is certain. The first uncertain (according to my very conservative estimation) is for n=21637448 (and then, there are 6 others before n=100000000).

But Kelly's code would take 4 days to give an answer for that n :D (and all other answers so far, way, way more. Milleniums for some, and only if zillions of terabytes of memory is provided)

So I say, not to be sure for n=21637448 is a pretty correct tradeoff (besides, the question is for n=1000). And anyway, we can do both: we can fall back on Kelly's code if mine reply "unsure", since it knows when it is unsure.

In worse case, computing with my code, then Kelly's code is mine is unsure, cost extra 1.32 μs over a 4 days computation :D.

So to remove this "unsure" problem, here is my final code

```py
def fibo_binet(size):
    phi=(1+math.sqrt(5))/2
    n=math.ceil(((size-1)*math.log(10)+0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(phi))
    l10=(n*math.log(phi)-0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(10)
    k10=((n-1)*math.log(phi)-0.5*math.log(5))/math.log(10)
    if int(l10)==int(k10)+1 and (l10-int(l10))>1e-14 and (k10-int(k10))>1e-14:
       return n
    else:
       return None

def fibo_int(n):
    a = b = i = 1
    goal = 10**(n-1)
    while a < goal:
        a, b, i = b, a+b, i+1
    return i

def fiboBest(n):
   b=fibo_binet(n)
   if b is None:
       return fibo_int(n)
   else:
       return b
```

That code runs in 1.32 μs 99999993 times out of 100000000, and in days 7 times out of 100000000 (in cases where other codes take at best 1.32 μs less, so days, and at most decades, centuries, ...)
And is always sure.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of recursively calculating every term each time, make an array of terms, then you can calculate a term by adding terms[-1] and terms[-2]

Comment: Not the best option, he don't need to keep all the fibonnacci numbers but just the last two

Comment: You can just keep them in 2 variables that you update at each iteration, the speed doesn't change, and memory footprint keeps constant