# One test case fails due to runtime error

Tags: python, math, fibonacci

I was trying Project Euler [problem 25](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler025) on HackerRank.

I attempted a brute force method using Binet's [Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html).

```
import math

for _ in range(int(input())):
    numLen = int(input())
    for x in range(1, 5000):
        fib = 1/pow(5,.5)*(pow(((1+pow(5,.5))/2),x) - pow(((1-pow(5,.5))/2),x))
        if(numLen == len(str(int(fib)))):
            print(x)
            break
```

Here 5000 is an arbitrary number based on the assumption input is not more than that and the problem is not here as its a runtime error which I'm think is because it's exceeding integer range(not sure).

It also calculates other test cases in less than 0.25 seconds.

I did some searching and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808763/non-brute-force-solution-to-project-euler-25).

but by that recurrence method:

```
import math

for _ in range(int(input())):
    a = 1
    b = 0
    n = int(input())
    term = 1
    while len(str(a)) != n:
        a, b = a+b, a
        term+=1
    print (term)
```

gives a timeout as it exceeds 10 seconds.

Can you please help me find a way to improve the first method and optimize the second method.

Note: I tried storing the pow() values in variables instead of recomputing and was of not much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the second approach in your example but instead of computing the value separately for every line in input compute the values `1...5000` once and cache them:

```
res = [0]
a = 0
b = 1
term = 1

while len(res) <= 5000:
    a, b = b, a + b
    if len(str(a)) >= len(res):
        res.append(term)
    term += 1

print('\n'.join(str(res[int(input())]) for _ in range(int(input()))))
```

For input `2 3 4` it will produce the expected output `12 17`. On my machine precomputing the values takes about 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`pow(x, y)` is always slower than `x**y` and also `pow()` method cannot be used for long integers.

Try `x**y` , it would be bit faster

Comment: Thanks for that! But again i repeat the problem is not time, it needs to be more space efficient.