# Maximum recursion depth error

Tags: python, tail-recursion

I've been scouring the internet and haven't been able to find anything that would help. I'm running a basic dfs algorithm in python. My error is in the `explore` subroutine of `dfs`

```
def dfs(graph):
    for node in graph:
       if not node in visited:
          explore(graph, node)


def explore(graph, v):
   visited.append(v)
   adjNode = graph[v]
   for i in range(0, len(adjNode)):
       if not adjNode[i] in visited:
          explore(graph, adjNode[i])
```

`visited` is a list I'm using to keep track of visited nodes and `graph` is a dictionary that holds the graph. 
With a standard recursion limit of 1000 I get this error

```
  File "2breakDistance.py", line 45, in explore
    explore(graph, adjNode[i], cycles)
  File "2breakDistance.py", line 45, in explore
    explore(graph, adjNode[i], cycles)
  File "2breakDistance.py", line 45, in explore
    explore(graph, adjNode[i], cycles)
  File "2breakDistance.py", line 45, in explore
    explore(graph, adjNode[i], cycles)
  File "2breakDistance.py", line 41, in explore
    adjNode = graph[v]
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

First of all, I'm not quite sure why the error is occurring in `adjNode = graph[v]` since `explore` is the recursive call and `adjNode` is just list assignment.

But to deal with the recursion error, I increased the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)` I no longer get the error, but the program quits right before the `adjNode = graph[v]` line and exits with no error. It never even reaches the end of `dfs` so I'm not quite sure what's going on. Thanks for reading all this and for any help!

Comment: Sounds like it would best to rework your algorithm to be iterative rather than recursive. See http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html

Comment: Hmm, a bit meta perhaps, but should this question be tagged `tail-recursion` since [Python cannot recognize/optimize tail recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion)?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the right `explore` function? The exceptions says: `explore(graph, adjNode[i], cycles)` (3 arguments) and the one you're showing only shows two `def explore(graph, v):`

Comment: `setrecursionlimit()` can be dangerous:  the C stack can overflow then, and Python can do nothing to detect that or recover from random-ish errors that result from the C stack overflowing.  Various kinds of data corruption are common then.  "Early" termination is one pleasant ;-) way for that to manifest.

Comment: I am calling the right explore, I just edited my function a little and  took out the cycles variable which was a book keeping variable to make it more understandable for the post. And I might try iterative instead and see if that helps with anything. And I had a feeling that something was still going wrong with the recursion when it terminated early!

Comment: @kinsigne: If you simplify your code, post the stack trace from the simplified version. If your simplified code is unrunnable or doesn't produce an error, you simplified out something important.

Comment: It would be a good idea to make `visited` a set instead of a list. Just use `.add` instead of `.append`. The `in` test will be much faster then

Answer (score 1):

Python is not very good at recursion. It doesn't do any tail-call optimization, and runs out of frame space pretty quickly unless you manually change the recursion limit. It's also slower to lookup and call a function again instead of keeping code in a loop without recursion.

Try rewriting this without recursion instead. The error can be happening anywhere a new frame is created, not just where *your* recursive call is, which is why the error is happening there.

Answer (score 0):

```
def explore(graph, v):
    visited.append(v)
    adjNode = graph[v]
    for i in range(0, len(adjNode)):
        if not adjNode[i] in visited:
            explore(graph, adjNode[i])
```

This isn't making sense to me, what is in a node object? Why are you assigning adjNode back to the value of the node that you pass in. Is adjNode meant to be calling like a "GetConnections()" sort of function instead?

The logic currently feels like it should be this:

```
1. For each Node in Nodes:
      2. Add Node to visited
         Get Nodes Connections
         Explore SubNodes: 
             Go to 2.
```