# computing the occurences of a number in a list with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

the task I am doing is:

> Given an array of ints, compute recursively the number of times that the value 11 appears in the array. We'll use the convention of considering only the part of the array that begins at the given index. In this way, a recursive call can pass index+1 to move down the array.

I need to do this recursively. I'm rather new at this, but I technically made it work.
I have the following:

```
def array11(arr, index, cnt=0, num=0):
    if(cnt==len(arr)-index):
        print("yay!!! number 11 appears %d times"%num)
        return
    elif(arr[index:][cnt]==11): 
        num+=1
        cnt+=1
        array11(arr,index,cnt,num)
    else: 
        cnt+=1
        array11(arr,index,cnt,num)
```

but I feel I did it a cheap way for some reason by adding the "cnt" and "num" parameters with default values. I just didn't know how to go through the "arr" array without a counter!!

So this this something acceptable? Would you have done it the same way?

thanks in advance

Comment: This is almost certainly too opinion based, and since it's working code, perhaps a better fit for Code Review.  That said, arrays aren't a recursive datatype (as opposed to singly linked lists), so this seems like a pretty natural solution given the datatype.  Plus, it's tail recursive, so it could be compiled down to a loop, which is good.

Comment: +1 for making an attempt before asking. I edited your title to reflect the problem at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You normally *return* the total count:

```
def array11(arr, index):
    if index == len(arr):
        return 0
    return (arr[index] == 11) + array11(arr, index + 1)
```

I am using a little Python trick here where `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `True` is equal to 1. As such, adding up booleans (or booleans and integers) results in the boolean values to be interpreted as integer numbers instead.

You'd use `print` then on whatever the outermost call to `array11()` returned.

Comment: but OP's was tail-recursive :|

Comment: That addition doesn't chain? `array11([11,2,3], 0)` would produce `1 + array11([11,2,3], 1)` -> `1 + 0 + array11([11,2,3], 2)` -> `1 + 0 + 0 + array11([11,2,3], 3)` -> `1 + 0 + 0 + 0` = `1` right ?

Comment: +1 but you might want to throw parenthesis around your boolean expression there to make it a little more clear what you're doing

Comment: @Josh: done, plus explanation added as to how `arr[index] == 11` is summable.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Ick, I need my tea still. Not that it matters, as Python doesn't optimise tail recursion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What do you mean by that? I don't know a whole lot about Python internals.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: You normally want to aim for tail recursion so the compiler can easily optimise the recursion away. [Python doesn't do this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Interesting. Offhand, do you know if other implementations do support this?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: No current Python implementations implement it, no. Python's creator is [on record as stating it is not a good idea](http://neopythonic.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html).

Comment: awesome, I found an easier way thanks to you:

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly acceptable, albeit not the *cleanest* way to perform tail recursion. What you are doing is called using an *accumulator* to keep track of your count, which allows you to have **tail recursion** (the more efficient type of recursion).

However, as BlackVegetable points out, Python doesn't allow you to reap the benefits of tail recursion, but it's definitely noteworthy to understand the difference between using an accumulator vs a top down approach as in Martijn Pieter's answer.

Comment: Using an accumulator isn't particularly *unclean*;  what might be cleaner is to make calls like `array11(arr,index,cnt+1,num+1)` rather than modifying cnt and num and then making the calls.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor sure, meant more the code itself. He could use an accumulator differently. And now your comment on the OP's question does ring true :)

Comment: Tail recursive calls are not optimized in Python, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 it can be as concise as this:

```
arr = [11, 0, 4, 7, 2, 11, 6, 11, 12]

def count11(arr):
    if not arr:
        return 0
    first, *rest = arr
    return (1 if first == 11 else 0) + count11(rest)

count11(arr) # 3
```

The list slicing may not be very efficient, but since we're talking about recursion in Python, in assume performance is not a factor.