# Why doesn't my function work?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

When I wrote this code in python-2.7 I got a message that runs again and again, can someone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
num = raw_input("enter your number : ")

def calc():
    if num == "1":
        print "ok"
    else:
        print "right"
    calc()

calc()
```

It prints `ok` or `right` over and over.

So what should I do if I want to go back to the initial state (asking for input) after each print?

Comment: Why are you yelling?

Comment: The edit makes it much clearer. Can someone put it off the on-hold list?

Comment: Maybe you'd like to put `num = raw_input("enter your number : ")` inside the function.

Comment: @Flying_Banana It's clear now, but seems like this question really is off-topic.

Comment: But as it stands in the current edit, there is desired behavior (ask for input again), current error (printing over and over without asking input), and sample code that produces this error, so it constitutes as a minimal, complete, and verifiable example by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is repeating itself because you call `calc()` again inside the `calc()` function, making it an infinite loop.

```
def calc():
    if num == "1":
        print "ok"
    else:
        print "right"
    calc()  # <-- Why is this here?
```

> So what should I do if I want to go back to the initial state (asking for input) after each print?

Then you need to ask for the input again inside the loop:

```
def calc():
    num = raw_input("enter your number : ")
    if num == "1":
        print "ok"
    else:
        print "right"
    calc()

calc()
```

Comment: While this works in principle, it will actually recurse indefinitely, adding a new function call to the stack every time. While it'll take a while, it's a waste and the interpreter is going to crash when the maximum recursion depth is exceeded.

Comment: I would almost agree with you, except code compiled with `gcc -O3` will perform tail recursion so there is no difference :)

Comment: @Fyling_Banana It's python, not C/++. CPython may be compiled with `-O3`, the code it executes isn't. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13592002/5349916. In fact, `def foo(): foo()` is enough to test this.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep calling the same function over and over again, you will reach a stack overflow sooner or later. In order to repeat something indefinitely, use a loop, e.g. `for` or `while`.

```
def calc():
  while True:
    num = raw_input("enter your number : ")
    if num == "1":
      print "ok"
    else:
      print "right"

calc()
```

You should also definitely consider adding a condition that exits your loop. For example, checking whether the input is `"q"` and then executing `break`:

```
  while True:
    num = raw_input("enter your number : ")
    if num == "q":
      break
    elif num == "1":
      print "ok"
    else:
      print "right"
```