# How to transform a list into a hierarchy dict

Tags: python

How would I turn a list like `["one","two","three","four"]` into something like `{"one": {"two": {"three":{"four"}}}}` where each item in the list would be a descendant of the other element in the dictionary? I think it could be done in a recursive function, but I'm not sure how.

This is what I tried:

```
l = ["one","two","three","four"]
d = {}

for v in l[:-1]:
    d[v] = {l}
    d = d[v]

print(d)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note, you're last element is a *`set`* not a `dict`.

Comment: Since python doesn't have tail-call optimization, you'll probably want to refactor to non-recursive or properly handle when the length of the input is too long for recursion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A recursive solution

```
def dictify(d):
    if len(d) == 1:
        return {d[0]}
    else:
        return {d[0]: dictify(d[1:])}
```

For example

```
>>> dictify(["one","two","three","four"])
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four'}}}}
```

Note that the in above solution, the inner-most object is actually a `set`, not a `dict`. If you want all objects to be `dict` then you can modify the solution to

```
def dictify(d):
    if len(d) == 1:
        return {d[0]: None}
    else:
        return {d[0]: dictify(d[1:])}
```

Resulting in

```
>>> dictify(["one","two","three","four"])
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four': None}}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted the structure to look like the following

```
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four': None}}}}
```

You could generate that with something like this. This solution uses recursion.

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]


def gen(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        key = arr.pop(0)
        val = gen(arr)

        dict = {}
        dict[key] = val
        return dict

print gen(arr)
```

Comment: Yep, saw that. Thanks for the update on that, I'll update my post.

Comment: @CoryKramer I think the statement is still valid: I would expect OP didn't intend to make a set as the last value.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd prefer a non-recursive solution:

```
def endeepen(lst):
    old = None
    for v in lst[::-1]:
        ret = {}
        ret[v] = old
        old = ret
    return ret
```

Just iterates the list in reverse and buries the each dct as the previous elements value:

```
>>> endeepen(l)
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four': None}}}}
```

---

If you *really* want the last element to be a set, you can do so with a minor correction:

```
def endeepen(lst):
    old = {lst[-1]}
    for v in lst[len(lst) - 2::-1]:
        ret = {}
        ret[v] = old
        old = ret
    return ret
```

which then gives:

```
>>> endeepen(l)
{'one': {'two': {'three': set(['four'])}}}
```

Note: In both cases, I haven't covered edge conditions, so empty or very short lists `len(1) <= 1` may misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ["one","two","three","four"]
d = {}

d2 = d
for v in l[:-1]:
    d2[v] = {}
    d2 = d2[v]
d2[l[-2]] = {l[-1]}
print(d)
>>> {'one': {'two': {'three': {'three': {'four'}}}}}
```