# Python: Transform a list of lists into a hierarchical dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, tree

I have some gene sequencing data like below:

```
data = [{'sequence': 'gene1__gene2__gene3', 'occurrence': 10},
        {'sequence': 'gene2__gene3', 'occurrence': 5},
        {'sequence': 'gene2', 'occurrence': 2},
        {'sequence': 'gene4', 'occurrence': 4}
       ]
```

I want to transform this into following (tree-like)`dictionary` data structure, where any sub-path tells me the co-occurrence count of that set of genes:

```
tree_dict = {
        'gene1': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 0, 'children': {'gene2': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 0, 'children': {'gene3': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 10, 'children': {}}}},
                                                            'gene3': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 0, 'children': {'gene2': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 10, 'children': {}}}},
                                                           }
                 },
        'gene2': {'occurrence': 17, 'self': 2, 'children': {'gene1': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 0, 'children': {'gene3': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 10, 'children': {}}}},
                                                            'gene3': {'occurrence': 15, 'self': 5, 'children': {'gene1': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 10, 'children': {}}}},
                                                           }
                 },
        'gene3': {'occurrence': 15, 'self': 0, 'children': {'gene1': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 0, 'children': {'gene2': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 10, 'children': {}}}},
                                                            'gene2': {'occurrence': 15, 'self': 5, 'children': {'gene1': {'occurrence': 10, 'self': 10, 'children': {}}}},
                                                           }
                 },
        'gene4': {'occurrence': 4, 'self': 4, 'children': {}}
       }
```

In the `tree_dict` above:

- `self` refers to occurrence of just the nodes in the (sub)path. For ex: `gene3` never exists all by itself and thus have `self` value of 0; while `gene2` exists all by itself `2` times and thus have the `self` value of 2.
- `occurrence` refers to occurrence of the nodes in the (sub)path both as substrings and whole.

**Code that I tried?**
I was trying with failure iterative approaches, when I know that the solution of this have to be a recursive function. Something similar to this question: [How to transform a list into a hierarchy dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286157/how-to-transform-a-list-into-a-hierarchy-dict). But I was not able to make any progress in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = [{'sequence': 'gene1__gene2__gene3', 'occurrence': 10},
        {'sequence': 'gene2__gene3', 'occurrence': 5},
        {'sequence': 'gene2', 'occurrence': 2},
        {'sequence': 'gene4', 'occurrence': 4}]

tree_dict = {}

def generate_tree(sequence, occurrence, curr_dict):
    gene_list = sequence.split('__')
    for gene in gene_list:
        if gene in curr_dict:
            curr_dict[gene]['occurrence'] += occurrence
        else:
            curr_dict[gene] = {'occurrence': occurrence, 'self': 0, 'children': {}}
        updated_list = gene_list.copy()
        updated_list.remove(gene)
        updated_sequence = '__'.join(updated_list)
        if updated_sequence != '':
            generate_tree(updated_sequence, occurrence, curr_dict[gene]['children'])
        else:
            curr_dict[gene]['self'] += occurrence

for item in data:
    generate_tree(item['sequence'], item['occurrence'], tree_dict)

print(tree_dict)
```