# How can I build a iterated function using the return value as the input parameter

Tags: python

For some function f and variable a,

```
b_1 = f(a), 
b_2 = f(b_1), 
b_3 = f(b_2) 
...
b_n = f(b_n-1)
```

I would like to do n-times by iterated method. In a functional way, this is accomplished by a function composition.

```
f...(f(f((a)))
```

Comment: Something like `functools.reduce(lambda b, _: f(b), range(n), a)`…

Comment: @deceze thanks. but how can I solve this problem with imperative loop without using the high-order function such as reduce?

Comment: `for _ in range(n): b = f(b)`…?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive your result by recusion

you can refer below pesudo code

```
#define  f(a):
    # do computation

    # if terminating condition
        # then return the computed result
    #else
        # return f(computed result)
```

Comment: This is a bad solution, as it will cause a stack overflow for a large enough `n`.

Comment: @deceze I think this will not cause stack overflow for large n because here tail recursion is used

Comment: python also do tail call eliminination

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion