# How to do recursion with more than limit digit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I want to do recursion with the program below but since the input number is too big (19 digits). It throws an error in my program
**MemoryError: Stack overflow** or **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison**. I've tried to reset the recursion limit using

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
```

But it is not helping. Do you have any solutions to handle this such large number?
This is my whole program.

```
def recursion(n):
    return 1 if n < 2 else n * recursion(n - 2)


string = str(recursion(1000000000000000000))
```

Comment: Sometimes recursion is not a useful approach.

Comment: Do you have suggestions for other approaches for me to use beside recursion?

Comment: If you are encountering a memory error and your implementation is correct, that almost certainly means you need to change to a non-recursive approach. 10^19 recursion depth is not even remotely possible on any existing computer

Comment: Even apart from the recursive limit problem, I doubt that you have the memory to hold `str(recursion(1000000000000000000))` or the time to calculate `recursion(1000000000000000000)`. Using logarithms you can verify that memory involved is infeasibly large. The function that you are trying to compute grows *faster* than any exponential function.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately [python doesn't optimize tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion) to iteration. But you can do it yourself:

```
def recursion(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1, 2):
        result *= i
    return result
```

If you really want it to be recursive then the only thing you can do is to increase recursion limit and stack size, but this is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your method but strangely the result is always 1. Do you know why? And plus the program never ends. It doesn't show any output.

Comment: @Vincent.N The code in this answer simply doesn't always return 1. If that is what you are observing -- check your indentation perhaps.

Comment: It 'never' ends because looping 1000000000000000000 times takes a lot of time. Add a simple print inside for loop to see how it's doing.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for answering. @JohnColeman sorry that was very stupid of me. I confused the i with 1 and didn't notice of it.

Comment: @RafalS I've tried that. That's a lot of numbers and it exceeds my expectation of run time. So I guess these methods are not yet efficient enough.

Comment: A quibble: this function only agrees with OP's function for even `n`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the practical limitations of recursion [without tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it).

Python has a guard against the number of recursive calls you can make in order to avoid a stack overflow. This is the `RecursionError` you are seeing:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def recursion(n):
...     return 1 if n < 2 else n * recursion(n - 2)
... 
>>> 
>>> string = str(recursion(1000000000000000000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in recursion
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in recursion
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in recursion
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Increasing is a possible solution, but it only removes the built-in guard. If enough recursive calls are made, you will eventually run out of memory, which is the second error you are getting (`MemoryError: Stack overflow` or a segmentation fault in my case).

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
>>> def recursion(n):
...     return 1 if n < 2 else n * recursion(n - 2)
... 
>>> string = str(recursion(1000000000000000000))
Segmentation fault
```

The idiomatic solution to this problem in Python would be to use iteration instead:

```
def iteration(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(n, 1, -2):
        result *= i
    return result
```

Running this example with your original input (`1e18`) won't terminate any time soon though. As the integer grows, it takes increasingly more time to compute, because the operations require using integer representations larger than 64-bit (or however many bits your CPU is able to represent with a single register).

Nevertheless, that would be the Pythonic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For even `n`, your function computes `2*4*6* ... *n`. It is easy to work out that this is the same as `2^(n/2) * (n/2)!`. For example, `2*4*6*8*10 = (2*1)*(2*2)*(2*3)*(2*4)*(2*5)` which is thus `2^5*(1*2*3*4*5) = 32*5!`. This can be quickly an efficiently computed by the function:

```
import math

def f(n):
    k = n//2
    return 2**k * math.factorial(k)
```

For odd `n`, it is slightly more complicated. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69162/294695) from Math Overflow.

By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), `f(n)` is asymptotically equivalent to `sqrt(pi*n)*(n/e)^(n/2)`. Plugging in `n = 10^18`, and taking the base-2 log of the result, you can see that `f(10^18)` would take roughly 3.6 [exabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) to store the resulting integer (which is probably more than your computer can handle).