# Adding numbers within a range of root values returns incorrect value

Tags: python, algorithm, treenode

I am working through LeetCode and this problem has me stuck.  I am given a root node of a binary search tree and I am asked to return the sum of all values between `L` and `R` inclusive:

Example:

```
Input: root = [10,5,15,3,7,null,18], L = 7, R = 15
Output: 32 (10+15+7)
```

This is my attempt:

```
class Solution:

    def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:
        value = 0
        
        if root.val >= L and root.val <= R:
            value += root.val
        
        return value
```

However, this is what it is returning:

```
Your input [10,5,15,3,7,null,18] 7 15
Output     10
Expected   32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, instead of `if root.val >= L and root.val <= R` you can simply use `L <= root.val <= R`.

Then, there are two more conditions to be defined. This'd pass through:

```
class Solution:
    def rangeSumBST(self, root, L, R):
        if not root:
            return 0

        summation = 0
        if root.val > L:
            summation += self.rangeSumBST(root.left, L, R)

        if root.val < R:
            summation += self.rangeSumBST(root.right, L, R)

        if L <= root.val <= R:
            summation += root.val

        return summation
```

Here is LeetCode's iterative solution using stack:

```
class Solution(object):
    def rangeSumBST(self, root, L, R):
        ans = 0
        stack = [root]
        while stack:
            node = stack.pop()
            if node:
                if L <= node.val <= R:
                    ans += node.val
                if L < node.val:
                    stack.append(node.left)
                if node.val < R:
                    stack.append(node.right)
        return ans
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're stopping at the root of the tree.
Look at the tree recursively.

Try

```py
class Solution:
    def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:
        if root is None or root.val < L or root.val > R:
            return 0
        return root.val + self.rangeSumBST(root.left, L, R) + self.rangeSumBST(root.right, L, R)
```

Comment: But what if I don't want to do recursion?  How can I fix my existing code?

Comment: @oo92 Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62085259/rewrite-the-recursive-function-into-tail-recursive-function/62085521#62085521) help?