# Python tail recursion optimization in this algo?

Tags: python, recursion

I got the following problem:
Let's consider the following encoding table:

```
0 -> A
1 -> B
2 -> C
...
```

- input: string containing a list of integers
- output: int representing the number of words that can be encoded from the input
- examples:

```
"0" -> 1 (word is A)
"10" -> 2 (words are BA and K)
"121" -> 3 (words are BCB, MB and BV)
```

I wrote this algo

```py
import string
sys.setrecursionlimit(100)  # limit the number of recursions to 100
# {0: 'a', 1: 'b', etc.}
dict_values = dict(zip(range(26), string.ascii_lowercase))

def count_split(list_numbers: list) -> int:
    if len(list_numbers) == 0:
        return 0

    elif len(list_numbers) == 1:
        return 1

    elif len(list_numbers) == 2:
        if int(list_numbers[0]) == 0:
            return 1

        elif 10 <= int("".join(list_numbers)) <= 25:
            return 2

        else:
            return 1

    else:  # list_numbers contains at least three elements
        if count_split(list_numbers[:2]) == 2:
            return count_split(list_numbers[1:]) + count_split(list_numbers[2:])

        else:
            return count_split(list_numbers[1:])

def get_nb_words(code: str) -> int:
    return count_split(list(code))

# print(get_nb_words("0124")) -> 3
# print(get_nb_words("124")) -> 3
# print(get_nb_words("368")) -> 1
# print(get_nb_words("322")) -> 2
# print(get_nb_words("12121212121212121212")) -> 10946
```

Surprisingly, this algo works on the last example `"12121212121212121212"`. I expected the number of recursions to be exceeded because at each step, the function `count_split` is called twice on a list. Thus, the number of calls is much more than 100 (even more than 1000) !

In the meanwhile I found [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion) saying that tail recursion is not optimized in Python, so I'm a bit suprised !

Could someone explain to me why the recursion limit is not exceed in this algorithm ?

Comment: It's a little late for me, but I think your maximum recursion *depth* (which is what matters) would only be about the length of the input string, no? Note, `recursionlimit` is a little misleading, it's actually the maximum depth of the call stack.

Comment: yes, so I guess that recursion *depth* (which is set to 1000 by default) is not *the number of times the function is called* but *the number of inputs with which the function is called*. Am I getting this right ?

Comment: No, it isn't the number of inputs with which the function is called. It's the maximum depth of the call stack, or is that what you meant? Again, sorry, it's late for me

Comment: oh ok the depth of the tree representing the successive calls, right ?

Comment: It's not a tree, it's a *stack*.

Comment: Well, the entirety of recursive calls can be seen as a tree if it is branching out, but yes, at any given moment it is just a stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You care about the recursion depth, i.e. the maximum depth (height?) of the call stack.

Here's an empirical approach: (code that measures the depth)

```
import string, sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100)  # limit the number of recursions to 100

dict_values = dict(zip(range(26), string.ascii_lowercase))
stack = []
max_depth = 0
def count_split(list_numbers: list) -> int:
    global max_depth
    stack.append(None)
    max_depth = max(max_depth, len(stack))
    if len(list_numbers) == 0:
        return 0

    elif len(list_numbers) == 1:
        return 1

    elif len(list_numbers) == 2:
        if int(list_numbers[0]) == 0:
            return 1

        elif 10 <= int("".join(list_numbers)) <= 25:
            return 2

        else:
            return 1

    else:  # list_numbers contains at least three elements
        if count_split(list_numbers[:2]) == 2:
            stack.pop()
            result = count_split(list_numbers[1:]) + count_split(list_numbers[2:])
            stack.pop(); stack.pop()
            return result

        else:
            result = count_split(list_numbers[1:])
            stack.pop()
            return result

def get_nb_words(code: str) -> int:
    return count_split(list(code))

print(get_nb_words("12121212121212121212"))
print(max_depth) # 20
```