# change the recursive function to tail recursive

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

```
def singlesR(xs):
  if xs != [] :
    return  [[xs[0]]] + singlesR(xs[1:])
  else :
      return []
```

<recursive function>

How to change to a tail recursive function?

```
#result value
singlesR([1,2,3,4]) == [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages. This clearly isn't C.

Comment: There is no built-in tail recursion in Python.

Comment: I want to understand how the tail recurs.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment and discussed further in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion) python does not have tail recursion optimization.

Other languages such as Haskell do support tail recursion.
this function could be rewritten in Haskell in as a tail recursive function like this:

```hs
singlesR = singlesR' []
  where singlesR' acc [] = acc
        singlesR' acc (x:xs) = singlesR' ([x]:acc) xs
```

The main observation here is that in the tail recursive version all of the work is done inside of the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

if you want this with a tail-call you need to add an accumulator:

```
def singlesR(xs, accumulator=[]):
    if not xs:
        return accumulator

    accumulator = accumulator + [xs[0]]
    return singlesR(xs[1:], accumulator)
```

note that now the last call before `return`ing is indeed the recursive call to `singlesR`.

but as stated in the comments: as there is no tail-call optimization in python there will be no performance gain.

note that in your version

```
return [[xs[0]]] + singlesR(xs[1:])
```

the call to `singlesR` is not in tail position - after it is called there is a call to `list.__add__`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I was very nervous when I visited the site for the first time and asked questions.
Nevertheless, it helped me a lot by telling me in detail.

Comment: How should I think about the process when I change it to tail recursion?

Comment: no problem! please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it is helpful.

Comment: how to "think about" recursion? follow the local variables in a debugger. or in [pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20singlesR%28xs,%20accumulator%3D%5B%5D%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20not%20xs%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20accumulator%0A%0A%20%20%20%20accumulator%20%3D%20accumulator%20%2B%20%5Bxs%5B0%5D%5D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20singlesR%28xs%5B1%3A%5D,%20accumulator%29%0A%0Aprint%28singlesR%28%5B0,%201,%202,%203%5D%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).