# If python don't have tail recurssion in it, then why my code on leetcode is working differently for different recursions?

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

As per the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion) tail recursion is not present in python. I was working on leetcode problem where two inputs are given, number and its power. The power can be negative also. I need to find out exponent using recursion.

This was my code which was not getting accepted:

```
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        def po(x,n):
            if n ==1:
                return x
            if n== 2:
                return x * x

            if n % 2==0:
                return po(x * x, n//2)
            else:
                return x * po(x * x,(n-1)//2)
        
        p = po(x,abs(n))

        if n < 0:
            return float(1)/p
        else:
            return p
```

For the above code I received error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
    return po(x * x, n//2)
Line 15 in po (Solution.py)
    return po(x * x, n//2)
Line 15 in po (Solution.py)
.
.
.
.
```

But for this code, it worked properly:

```
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        def po(x,n):
            if n ==0:
                return 1
            if n < 0:
                return 1.0/po(x,-1*n)

            if n % 2==0:
                return po(x * x, n//2)
            else:
                return x * po(x * x,(n-1) // 2)
        
        return po(x,n)
```

Comment: FYI, your  `po` function isn't tail recursive to begin with, so whether or not Python includes optimizations for tail recursion is irrelevant.

Comment: Python has recursion but not tail recursion -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion

Comment: Since the two codes a fairly different, in the first case you probably simply have an infinite recursion because of a missing base case, or at least *too much* recursion, which you don't have in the other case…!?

Comment: @rasjani Python has tail recursion if you write tail recursive code, it just might not *optimise* tail recursive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tail recursion isn't the issue.

In the original code, if `n` is `0`, it will just keep recursing without end, until it reaches the maximum recursion limit.  It goes past the checks for `1` and `2`, and then, since `0` is even, it does `return po(x * x, n//2)`.  Since `n//2` is also `0`, it never ends.  You just need to add a check for `n` equal to `0`.