# Understanding how a SQL recursive cte evaluates

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have the following CTE that I'd like to understand in depth a bit more (i.e., how it evaluates behind the scenes):

```
WITH RECURSIVE example (loc, a,b,c) AS (
    SELECT 'anchor', 1,2,3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'recursive', a*a, b*b, c*c FROM example WHERE c < 50
) SELECT * FROM example;

┌───────────┬───┬─────┬──────┐
│ loc       ┆ a ┆ b   ┆ c    │
╞═══════════╪═══╪═════╪══════╡
│ anchor    ┆ 1 ┆   2 ┆    3 │
│ recursive ┆ 1 ┆   4 ┆    9 │
│ recursive ┆ 1 ┆  16 ┆   81 │
└───────────┴───┴─────┴──────┘
```

Is the following a correct understanding of building the `example` (cte) table?

1. It starts with the simple `SELECT` anchor, which gives us the starting result-set.

```
SELECT 'anchor', 1, 2, 3
┌───────────┬───┬─────┬──────┐
│ loc       ┆ a ┆ b   ┆ c    │
╞═══════════╪═══╪═════╪══════╡
│ anchor    ┆ 1 ┆   2 ┆    3 │
└───────────┴───┴─────┴──────┘
```

2. Now it runs the recursive case and for the `example` table it will evaluate it iteratively, for the first row it has values of `('anchor', 1, 2, 3)` and so the statement it now runs to generate the second item (first recursive case) is:

```
SELECT 'recursive' a*a, b*b, c*c FROM (VALUES ('anchor', 1,2,3)) AS example (loc,a,b,c)
WHERE c < 50
┌───────────┬───┬─────┬──────┐
│ loc       ┆ a ┆ b   ┆ c    │
╞═══════════╪═══╪═════╪══════╡
│ recursive ┆ 1 ┆   4 ┆    9 │
└───────────┴───┴─────┴──────┘
```

3. Let's do the same thing again, now using the values from the current iteration:

```
SELECT 'recursive', a*a, b*b, c*c FROM (VALUES ('recursive', 1,4,9)) AS example (loc,a,b,c)
WHERE c < 50
┌───────────┬───┬─────┬──────┐
│ loc       ┆ a ┆ b   ┆ c    │
╞═══════════╪═══╪═════╪══════╡
│ recursive ┆ 1 ┆  16 ┆   81 │
└───────────┴───┴─────┴──────┘
```

4. We do the same thing again. However, this time `c` will be more than 100, and so it will return no rows:

```
SELECT 'recursive', a*a, b*b, c*c FROM (VALUES ('recursive', 1,16,81)) AS example (loc,a,b,c)
WHERE c < 50
[empty]
```

Because we have no new results in the iteration and the cte stops when we have a fixpoint, we know that our cte is finished. Here is how it looks then in total, "iterating" with successive `UNION ALL`s instead of using the `RECURSIVE` keyword:

```
WITH example (loc, a,b,c) AS (
    SELECT 'anchor', 1, 2, 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'recursive', a*a, b*b, c*c FROM (VALUES ('anchor',1,2,3)) example (loc,a,b,c) WHERE c < 50
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'recursive', a*a, b*b, c*c FROM (VALUES ('recursive',   1,4,9)) example (loc,a,b,c) WHERE c < 50
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'recursive', a*a, b*b, c*c FROM (VALUES ('recursive', 1,16,81)) example (loc,a,b,c) WHERE c < 50
) 
SELECT * FROM example

┌───────────┬───┬────┬────┐
│ loc       ┆ a ┆ b  ┆ c  │
╞═══════════╪═══╪════╪════╡
│ anchor    ┆ 1 ┆  2 ┆  3 │
│ recursive ┆ 1 ┆  4 ┆  9 │
│ recursive ┆ 1 ┆ 16 ┆ 81 │
└───────────┴───┴────┴────┘
```

I know this is a little bit 'of a stretch' how I wrote the cte out in long-form, but I was wondering if that seems like it is correct or accurate in my understanding of it.

Comment: Which DBMS: SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL, something else?

Comment: Correct in essence, except that the SQL Server implementation works on a row-by-row stack based evaluation (which means that analytical functions such as `ROW_NUMBER` don't work properly).

Comment: @Charlieface if I'm not mistaken I believe most (if not all) implementations do not allow an analytic function in the recursive case. Here's an example from Snowflake -- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte#overview-of-recursive-cte-syntax

Comment: as charlieface, pointed already out as recursion goees row by row, it will never work with window functions in the cte but you could use the outside if need be in another cte

Comment: Postgres does allow it, and works as expected https://dbfiddle.uk/w9-tL_dq but SQL Server allows it and it doesn't work properly https://dbfiddle.uk/hRRdin19 Others mostly don't allow it, correct. Anyway, what exactly is your question? You seem to have a good grasp of it?

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the fiddles and information. Is my understanding mostly correct, or anything that is inaccurate with how it's (usually?) processed?