# Recursion. Slice number to list of digits using recursions

Tags: python, recursion

```
def slice_num(num, lst=None):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []
    if num > 0:
        lst.append(num % 10)
        slice_num(num//10, lst)
    return lst[::-1]


print(slice_num(564))
```

Is it the correct way, or was a better choice??

Comment: On the surface with no other context, recursion appears to be (and feels like) the wrong tool for the job, and unnecessarily complex, *especially* in Python.

Comment: The output is `[5, 6, 4]` which seems to be correct... What are you asking?

Comment: You aren't: you are ignoring the list returned by the recursive call. The fact that you are also modifying the list argument in-place muddies the waters a bit, though: what is `slice_num` supposed to *do*?

Comment: how do it better? idk...

Comment: If you are just trying to break a number up into its decimal digits, skip the expensive recursion and do something like `return [int(x) for x in str(num)]`

Comment: Is "Need use recurcion" a homework requirement?

Comment: @chepner slice_num need to repeat slice until it can slice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split an integer into a list of digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1906717/6045800)

Comment: @JohnColeman just learning recursion. i know this was bad practic for this task use a recursion

Comment: @Tomerikoo no, want do it with recursion

Comment: And you seem to have done it already. So what is your question?

Comment: @Tomerikoo asking is it correct or can make this task any better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursion extracting digits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10571797/6045800)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt seems fine.  An alternative that's a modification of answer [Recursion extracting digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571797/recursion-extracting-digits/10572125#10572125) that:

- Avoids needing an extra argument that's modified
- Is shorter (single line), so perhaps simpler

**Alternative**

```
def slice_num(n):
    return [n] if n < 10 else slice_num(n // 10) + [n % 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is reverse the order of your `lst.append` and recursive calls, so that the *quotient* gets turned into a list of digits before adding the *remainder* to the end of the list. Then you don't need to reverse the list before returning it.

```
def slice_num(num, lst=None):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []
    if num > 0:
        slice_num(num//10, lst)
        lst.append(num % 10)

    return lst
```

---

There are a number of ways to simplify this.

1. You can get the quotient and the remainder with a single call:

   ```
   def slice_num(num, lst=None):
       if lst is None:
           lst = []
       if num > 0:
           q, r = divmod(num, 10)
           slice_num(q, lst)
           lst.append(r)
       return lst
   ```
2. Split this into two functions: a recursive function that modifies `lst` in place but does not return it, and a wrapper that *only* takes a number and ensures that the helper is initially called with an empty list.

   ```
   def slice_num(num: int) -> [int]:
       lst = []
       _slice_helper(num, lst)
       return lst

   def _slice_helper(num: int, lst: list[int]) -> None:
       if num > 0:
           q, r = divmod(num, 10)
           _slice_helper(q, lst)
           lst.append(r)
   ```

   This follows the Python convention of *either* modifying a list in place *or* returning a modified value, not both.
3. Note that you can use `divmod` *first*, and use `q == 0` as your base case. This lets you append `r` to the list unconditionally, as when `q == 0` then `r == num`. It also eliminates a recursive call `_slice_helper(0, lst)`.

   ```
   def _slice_helper(num, lst):
       q, r = divmod(num, 10)
       if q > 0:
           _slice_helper(q, lst)
       lst.append(r)
   ```

Answer (score -1):

If you still insist in using recursion despite the suggestion given from the comments here is a simple approach:

```py
def slice_num(num):
    if num < 0:
        num = -num
    if num == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return slice_num(num // 10) + [num % 10]

print(slice_num(564))
```

You could even use a one line code if only understand what the above code does:

```py
def slice_num(num):
    return slice_num(num // 10) + [num % 10] if num else []
    
print(slice_num(564))
```

Both approach will produce the same outpu.
Output:

```
[5, 6, 4]
```

Comment: This has O(n^2) complexity due to the repeated concatenation of a short list to a longer one, rather than the O(n) complexity obtained by appending to the list in-place.

Comment: @chepner Can you show a solution with better complexity?

Comment: @chepner All of your solutions take O(n^2) as well.

Comment: How so? `lst.append` is (amortized) O(1), not O(n) like `list.__add__`.

Comment: @chepner Due to your divisions.